# Block portrait view in ipad using jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile for my app and want to block portrait view in Ipad. I have tried dozen of methods but not getting any solution.Please help.

Comment: No website shold not be turn to right or portrait view

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970367/screen-orientation-ios